# EC2: Waiting until a new instance is in running state

Tags: amazon-ec2

I would like to create a new instance based on my stored AMI.

I achieve this by the following code:

```
RunInstancesRequest rir = new RunInstancesRequest(imageId,1, 1);
// Code for configuring the settings of the new instance
...
RunInstancesResult runResult = ec2.runInstances(rir);
```

However, I cannot find a wait to "block"/wait until the instance is up and running apart from Thread.currentThread().sleep(xxxx) command.

On the other hand, StartInstancesResult and TerminateInstancesResult gives you a way to have access on the state of the instances and be able to monitor any changes. But, what about the state of a completely new instance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Waiting for the EC2 instance to get ready is a common pattern. In the Python library boto you also solve this with `sleep` calls:

```
   reservation = conn.run_instances([Instance configuration here])
   instance = reservation.instances[0]

   while instance.state != 'running':
       print '...instance is %s' % instance.state
       time.sleep(10)
       instance.update()
```

With this mechanism you will be able to poll when your new instance will come up.

Comment: I didn't realize there was an update method. That's very good to know. Thank you. **However**, the current best solution is @Zags `instance.wait_until_running()`

Comment: @BrunoBronosky it depends on your goal. I need to wait until the instance is running and status checks have passed. Based on that, you cannot use Zags solution, since this will almost immediately resolve.

Comment: An update: If running the loop above using boto3, then instance.load() should be used instead of instance.update().

Answer (score 34):

boto3 has:

```
instance.wait_until_running()
```

From the [boto3 docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance.wait_until_running):

> Waits until this Instance is running. This method calls `EC2.Waiter.instance_running.wait()` which polls `EC2.Client.describe_instances()` every 15 seconds until a successful state is reached.  An error is returned after 40 failed checks.

Answer (score 13):

From the [AWS CLI changelog for v1.6.0](http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/CLI/0628285644028736):

> Add a wait subcommand that allows for a command to block until an AWS
>   resource reaches a given state ([issue 992](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/pull/992), [issue 985](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/pull/985))

I don't see this mentioned in the documentation, but the following worked for me:

```
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids "i-XXXXXXXX"
aws ec2 wait instance-running --instance-ids "i-XXXXXXXX"
```

The `wait instance-running` line did not finish until the EC2 instance was running.

I don't use Python/boto/botocore but assume it has something similar.  Check out [waiter.py on Github](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/1039d1b5f1e4c1c94336560700a76214e33657d3/botocore/waiter.py).

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you are trying to do (and how many servers you plan on starting), instead of polling for the instance start events, you could install on the AMI a simple program/script that runs once when the instance starts and sends out a notification to that effect, i.e. to an AWS SNS Topic.

The process that needs to know about new servers starting could then subscribe to this SNS topic, and would receive a push notifications each time a server starts.

Solves the same problem from a different angle; your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Go use Boto3's `wait_until_running` method:

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance.wait_until_running

Comment: I have tried this but although it does wait,  I can SSH to the instance until  a while later >10 secs and < 60 secs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use boto3 waiters, 
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#waiters

for this ex: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Waiter.InstanceRunning

Or in Java https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/
I am sure there are waiters implemented in all the AWS sdks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following shell script using AWS CLI to wait for the instance to be running and complete status checks successfully:

```bash
timeout=600  # Timeout in seconds
start_time=$(date +%s)

until [ "$(aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-id ${INSTANCE_ID} --query 'InstanceStatuses[0].InstanceStatus.Status' --output text)" = "ok" ] && \
      [ "$(aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-id ${INSTANCE_ID} --query 'InstanceStatuses[0].SystemStatus.Status' --output text)" = "ok" ] && \
      [ "$(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids ${INSTANCE_ID} --query 'Reservations[0].Instances[0].State.Name' --output text)" = "running" ]; do
  current_time=$(date +%s)
  elapsed_time=$((current_time - start_time))

  if [ "$elapsed_time" -ge "$timeout" ]; then
    echo "Timeout reached. Instance didn't reach the desired state within $timeout seconds."
    exit 1
  fi

  sleep 5
  echo "Waiting for instance to be running and complete status checks..."
done

echo "Instance is now running fine and status checks have been completed!"
```

Note: `${INSTANCE_ID}` is the ID of the AWS EC2 instance.

Reference: [Wait for an AWS EC2 instance to be running and complete status checks](https://github.com/abdullahkhawer/devops-helper-scripts/blob/main/terraform/wait_for_aws_ec2_instance_to_be_running_and_ready.tf)