# Get the public IPv4 address of a newly created amazon ec2 instance with boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am creating a ec2 instance with boto3 and I want print the ip address of that new instance.

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

# create the instance 
new_instance = ec2.create_instances(
    ImageId='###', 
    MinCount = 1, 
    MaxCount = 1, 
    InstanceType = 't2.nano',
    KeyName = "key",
    SecurityGroupIds = ["###"]
)

... wait until running ...
ip = new_instance[0].ipv4 # something like this
```

Is there a way to do something like this after it is running?

Comment: Just combine this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19055049/13070 and this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53221955/13070

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[ec2.create_instances](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.create_instances) returns a list of [ec2.Instance objects](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance).  ec2.Instance objects have an attribute named `private_ip_address`.  You can use that to get the private IP address.

A side note (based on the comments in your code example) you can also use the [wait_until_running](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance.wait_until_running) waiter to have your code halt until the instance is running.

```
# create the instance 
new_instance = ec2.create_instances(...)

# use a waiter on the instance to wait until running
new_instance[0].wait_until_running()

ip = new_instance[0].private_ip_address
public_ip = new_instance[0].public_ip_address
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the public ip address when it is created? I want to ssh on to the server after it is created.

Comment: Check out the linked documentation.  There is a ‘public_ip_address’ that should give you that

Comment: You must call `new_instance[0].reload()` or `public_ip_address` will be `None`

Answer (score 1):

You can `wait_until_running()` and then `reload()` to learn the public IP address of an instance.

```
# Create new instance
new_instance = ec2.create_instances(...)[0]

# Wait until instance enters the running state
new_instance.wait_until_running()

# Load updated attributes to populate public_ip_address
new_instance.reload()

# Read public IP address
ip = new_instance.public_ip_address
```